# How to add long text shadow in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried but it was not a long style shadow.

```
let myString = "Show Your Creativity"

myLabel.layer.masksToBounds = false
myLabel.layer.shouldRasterize = true
myLabel.layer.rasterizationScale = 10

// Create a shadow
let myShadow = NSShadow()
myShadow.shadowBlurRadius = 1
myShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
myShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.gray

// Create an attribute from the shadow
let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedStringKey.shadow: myShadow ]

// Add the attribute to the string
let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttribute)

// set the attributed text on a label
myLabel.attributedText = myAttrString // can also use with UITextView
```

Current result ... 
[image]

I want an effect like given image. 
[image]

Comment: Can you add an image of your current result?

Comment: Current result image added

Comment: Badly done, duplicate the text layer. Paint it in gray. Move it from current position to 1;1 offset. Duplicate it, Move it from current position to 1;1 offset. etc until you get the total offset of 40;40. Combine all these layers. Add extra effect like a blur or gradient mask to replicate the fading. That's a "hard" way of doing it but that's the main logic behind that effect.

Answer (score 0):

The effect you want to reproduce is not made by adding a shadow to text - as a shadow will follow and extend the curves in the characters.

The image you have linked to seems to be using a linear gradient masked by the tops of the text.

Reproducing this programmatically would be easier done in Sketch/PaintCode using text outlines to form masks and the linear gradient, and then export the result to iOS-compliant code. This will give you resolution independence and a small file size.

Or ship the bitmap image from an illustration app.

Or do you need dynamic text?

Comment: I want to do to in dynamic text.

Comment: You're going to have to draw in a CGContext. Stamping the text pixels for the distance and angle you want, using a solid color. Then draw a linear gradient mask on top of the streaking text. Finally, render the white text on top of that.